# "Dysfunctional" vs. "disfunctional"

Tags: etymology, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the proper spelling: “disfunction” or “dysfunction”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24604/which-is-the-proper-spelling-disfunction-or-dysfunction)

What's the rationale behind *dysfunctional* being spelled *dys-* and not *dis-*?

Comment: Dysfunctional has dysfunctional spelling. It's self-describing.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24604/which-is-the-proper-spelling-disfunction-or-dysfunction

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [WordReference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1450998) on Dysfunction vs. Disfunction:

> *dys-* is a Greek prefix meaning "bad", "abnormal", "difficult", or
>   "impaired".
>   *dis-* is a Latin prefix with none of the above meanings.
>
> *dys-* has the right meaning, but function is a Latin word. Hence the
>   confusion.

Latin *dis-* can mean "lack of", "not", "opposite of", "away from".

This all explains why something *dys*-functional has a bad or abnormal function, rather than a lack of function that *dis*-functional implies.

Comment: +1 So "dysfunctional" is dysfunctional but not disfunctional? SCNR :-)

Comment: Nonfunctional is standard for lacking function or being out of working order.

Comment: Malfunction is Latin for the Greek dysergy, but the latter is used to mean the contrary of synergy, which means collaboration or any activity that will make the whole be more that the sum of the parts. Dysfunctional, of which I ignore the origin, is not the only Greek-Latin construct in English. Other examples include hyper_real, hyper_active, mega_city, micro_nutrient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rationale, it's just one of the countless quirks of natural language.

The *dis-* prefix comes from Latin, *dys-* from Greek. They have some overlap in meaning, and with *-functional*, both could be used.

Now, *function* has Latin roots, so *disfunctional* would make more sense, in the way that both prefix and suffix come from Latin. However, *dysfunctional* has come to be the more commonly used spelling, disregarding the different roots of prefix and suffix.

Comment: I beg to differ - there *is* [some rationale](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45630/dysfunctional-vs-disfunctional/45641#45641).

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary records *disfunctional* as a variant spelling of (the more usual) *dysfunctional*.